# How can I access a contact's phone number in a PhoneGap running on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am attempting to access a contact's phone number in PhoneGap "Cordova 1.6.1" and send messages to this number.  I have been testing the application on the Android mobile platform and I am able to access the name of a contact using this function:

```
    $('#contacts').append('<option value="'+contacts[i].name+'" >' + contacts[i].name.formatted + '</select>');
```

However, when I enter:

```
     contacts[i].phoneNumbers.formatted
```

The output is Undefined.

What is the issue I am running into?  How may I properly access a contact's phone number in a PhoneGap android application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

phoneNumbers is an array, so you need to index into it.

```
for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
     alert("Type: " + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].type + "\n" + 
           "Value: "  + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value + "\n" + 
           "Preferred: "  + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].pref);
}
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#ContactField

Comment: Perfect, the only thing to add is to check contacts[i].phoneNumbers to see if it is null. If a contact has no phone numbers the array will be set to null.

Answer (score 4):

check out if u'r phoneNumbers array is not null

something like this

```
if (contacts[i].phoneNumbers){
for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
     alert(     " "  + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value + "\n" + 
           );
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://github.com/dbaq/cordova-plugin-contacts-phone-numbers to retrieve only the contacts with at least one phone number.